# Issue to handle React-Hook-Form errors object in combination with es6 literal templates

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hook-form, template-literals

The code below shows a table where I have a series of rows and columns based on the following arrays:

```
const weekDays = [
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday",
  "Saturday",
  "Sunday",
];

const timeWindows = [
  "openOrder",
  "closeOrder",
  "openPickupOrder",
  "closePickupOrder",
];
```

Based on the above values, I also dynamically generate the fields names by using es6 literal templates.

The problem starts when I try using the react-form-hook `errors` object in combination with the dynamically generated names (es6 literal templates). Errors don't work.

```
     <table>
        <tbody>
          {weekDays.map((day) => (
            <tr key={day}>
              <td>{day}</td>
              <td>
                <ToggleButton label={day} statusRow={statusRow} />
              </td>
              {timeWindows.map((window) => (
                <td key={`${day}${window}`}>
                  <input
                    {...register(`${window}${day}`, {
                      required: true,
                    })}
                    type="time"
                  />
                  {`${errors}.${window}${day}` && ( <---- ISSUE IS HERE
                    <span>This field is required</span>
                  )}
                </td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

I'm trying to combine an es6 literal template with an object and have in return the following:

```
errors.openOrderMonday
```

If I `console.log(`${errors}`)` I get [object Object], and if I try `console.log(`errors.${window}${day}`), yes it returns the full string (above) but it's NOT read as an object.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks
Joe

Comment: try:  `{errors[\`${window}${day}\`]}`

Comment: unfortunately that's returns `undefined`

Comment: then there must be something wrong the way you are using `register`. I usually do it like this `ref={register({validate: { validationMethod: (value) => /* validation return true/false*/ },required: true})}` or `ref={register({ required: true })}`

Comment: HI Pranay, as you can see from the code above, I use register as explained in the reach-hook-form docs: `<input {...register(`${window}${day}`, {required: true,})} name={`${window}${day}`}/>

Comment: It is working https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-agnesi-fsyt41?file=/src/App.js

react-hook-form v7 -> `const { register, formState: { errors }, handleSubmit } = useForm();`

Comment: you must update your question.

Comment: Please do a plain `console.log(errors)` and show us the result. ``errors[`${window}${day}`]`` (or simpler, just `errors[window+day]`) will be equivalent to the desired `errors.openOrderMonday`, so if it's `undefined`, then apparently the `errors` object doesn't have that property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I had 2 issues here:

- I wasn't able to use literal templates with an object to display errors
- With the solution suggested by other devs, the `errors` object was returning undefined

***Cause of the issue:***

- Issue 1 was caused by the code structure
- Issue 2 was caused by the fact that in the component AND its parent, I was initializing `errors` and `register`. Practically I was doing it twice.

***Fix:***

- Issue 1: the initial suggestion by **Pranay Nailwal** fixed the issue `` errors[`${window}${day}`] ``
- Issue 2: Instead of initializing `errors` and `register` twice, I passed those as `props` from the parent component

I removed this from my child component:

```
const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();
```

I used this:

```
const { register, errors } = props;
```

Thanks everyone for the help.